# ignore multiple folders in same root

Tags: git, gitignore

I stumble upon this rule in .gitignore file

```
src/ms.net/CrmPackageAll/*.suo[!!-~]*.user[!!-~]bin[!!-~]obj
```

looks like which means to ignore

```
-- files ending with .suo and .user
-- folders bin and obj
```

but when I typed git status, it still show me bin and obj folders in untracked files, whats [!!-~]? not able to find any documentation for that and how I can ignore bin and obj folder in single rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see that format in [gitignore man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

If you need to ignore:

- files ending with `.suo` and `.user`
- folders `bin` and `obj`

Your `.gitignore` would be:

```
*.suo
*.user
bin/
obj/
```

If a git status still shows those files/folders, that means they were tracked.
You would need to remove them first:

For instance:

```
git rm --cached -r bin/
git commit -m "remove bin"
```

Then the git status would not list that `bin/` folder anymore.